# zsh: killed python3 model.py

Tags: python, terminal, zsh

Have been looking for an answer to my specific problem but wasn't sure of what was best way to go about it. Getting this error when running a python script through the mac terminal.

Have seen people have turned off system integrity protection, but that doesn't sound very safe. What is recommended?

note: dmesg printed 'Unable to obtain kernel buffer: Operation not permitted'

Comment: What makes you think that this is related to zsh?

Comment: It could be because you don't have privileges to run the code. Try to run it using sudo.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.